# HTML5 question

Tags: html

What does it mean `but with no media element descendants` can someone give an example of the wrong and correct way?

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Comment: Here is the link http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#audio

Answer (score 0):

That means that you cannot nest an AUDIO or VIDEO element inside an AUDIO element. You cannot do this:

```
<audio>
    <audio></audio>
</audio>
```